# How to ignore all CSS elements in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, jquery-mobile

I want to use my own CSS on a mobile webpage, but also use jQuery mobile for a menu slide.

How can I ignore ALL their CSS elements?

I know `data-role="none"` attribute would work, but can't apply it to all my elements.

I also tried including my CSS after jQuery CSS, but it didn't work.

Comment: Would be handy if there would be a `$(*).css("*", "none !important")` or alternatively, don't include the stylesheet :)

Comment: Regarding the data-role attribute, why can't you apply it to all elements? Because there is to many elements or because you want to exclude a few elements?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `autoInitializePage` option to `false` in a `mobileinit` event handler so jQuery Mobile won't automatically initialize anything. You can then initialize a single widget or set of widgets by calling `.trigger("create")` on their parent elements.

Documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bBTtN/1/

Note that you need to bind to the `mobileinit` event in the proper place, after jQuery core has been included but before jQuery Mobile has been included.

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Also note that by default, jQuery Mobile sets `visibility : hidden` on the `<body>` element, so you'll need a CSS rule to overwrite that:

```
body {
    visibility : visible !important;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't include their       css.

Comment: @Constantino: Could you copy their CSS any remove and styles you don't want and use the copy instead?

Comment: tried that too, but didn't manage to work it out.. I thought there would be some other way

Comment: You said you want to ignore ALL their styles.. Then the answer is simple ;) Of course you need to include styles for what you need. But definitely it will work.

Comment: you can't use jquery mobile without including THEIR css.

Comment: @MichalKlouda Because jQuery Mobile adds a bunch of HTML structure to its widgets, and without jQuery Mobile's CSS, that HTML structure will not look like what the O.P. wants (a single widget initialized).

Comment: @Jasper I understand, and I upvoted your answer. I just wanted to point out the contradiction, when someone wants to remove all classes and not to remove them at the same time.