# CSS not working when using jquery and jquery.mobile together

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

In my page, I use jquery(2.2.0) and jquery.mobile(1.4.5). Until now it worked like a charm, but now I'm trying to use a pure CSS3 modal popup and its not working due to the jquery libraries. If I have both in the page the popup does not work, but if I remove one of them it start working fine. I tried to debug what is going on but no luck right now.

I'm posting the code and I hope anyone can help me with this.

```
<div>
    <div class="partnerLlistat">
        <a id="link2" href="#popup2">
            <div id="partnerBox2" class="partnerBox">
                <h3>Nom: aaa</h3>
                <p>Tipus de servei: aaa</p>
            </div>
        </a>

        <div id="popup2" class="overlay">
            <div class="inpopup2">
                <h3>Nom: aaa</h3>
                <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                <h4>Entitat: aaa</h4>
                <p>Tipus de servei: aaa</p>
                    <p>Adreça: aaa</p>
                    <p>Telèfon: 111</p>
                    <p>Pàgina web: <a ref="external" target="_blank" href="http://aaa.net">http://aaa.net</a></p>
                    <p>Correu electrònic: aaa@gmail.com</p>
                    <p>Avantatge que ofereix: aaa aaa</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a id="link3" href="#popup3">
            <div id="partnerBox3" class="partnerBox">
                <h3>Nom: bbb bbb</h3>
                <p>Tipus de servei: bbb</p>
            </div>
        </a>

        <div id="popup3" class="overlay">
            <div class="inpopup3">
                <h3>Nom: bbb bbb</h3>
                <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                <h4>Entitat: bbb</h4>
                <p>Tipus de servei: bbb</p>
                    <p>Adreça: bbb</p>
                    <p>Telèfon: 111</p>
                    <p>Pàgina web: <a ref="external" target="_blank" href="http://bbb.net">http://bbb.net</a></p>
                    <p>Correu electrònic: bbb@gmail.com</p>
                    <p>Avantatge que ofereix: bbb bbb</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a id="link4" href="#popup4">
            <div id="partnerBox4" class="partnerBox">
                <h3>Nom: ccc ccc</h3>
                <p>Tipus de servei: ccc</p>
            </div>
        </a>

        <div id="popup4" class="overlay">
            <div class="inpopup4">
                <h3>Nom: ccc ccc</h3>
                <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                <h4>Entitat: ccc</h4>
                <p>Tipus de servei: ccc</p>
                    <p>Adreça: ccc</p>
                    <p>Telèfon: 111</p>
                    <p>Pàgina web: <a ref="external" target="_blank" href="http://ccc.net">http://ccc.net</a></p>
                    <p>Correu electrònic: ccc@gmail.com</p>
                    <p>Avantatge que ofereix: ccc ccc</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a id="link5" href="#popup5">
            <div id="partnerBox5" class="partnerBox">
                <h3>Nom: ddd ddd</h3>
                <p>Tipus de servei: ddd</p>
            </div>
        </a>

        <div id="popup5" class="overlay">
            <div class="inpopup5">
                <h3>Nom: ddd ddd</h3>
                <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                <h4>Entitat: ddd</h4>
                <p>Tipus de servei: ddd</p>
                    <p>Adreça: ddd</p>
                    <p>Telèfon: 111</p>
                    <p>Pàgina web: <a ref="external" target="_blank" href="http://ddd.net">http://ddd.net</a></p>
                    <p>Correu electrònic: ddd@gmail.com</p>
                    <p>Avantatge que ofereix: ddd ddd</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:125px"></div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to format the CSS code correctly, so check it in the jsfiddle link.

As you can see, in jsfiddle is working fine, but because I don't know how to insert the libraries correctly. The best way to try it is doing it in your computer.

[check the code](https://jsfiddle.net/saqonfnf/)

Comment: Ok. I found how to reproduce the same in jsfiddle. Check this new link https://jsfiddle.net/saqonfnf/1/
I just added the jquery version in the jquery box and you can find the jquery.mobile version in external resources

Comment: so what's the expected behavior vs actual behavior of this fiddle?

Comment: The expected behavior is that the modal popup works. If you check the first link https://jsfiddle.net/saqonfnf/ must work like this. If you check the second link with the jquery libraries it doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/saqonfnf/1/ And I need that it works with the libraries

Comment: the one with both libraries *does* work

Comment: No, it doesn't. The one with both libraries does not work https://jsfiddle.net/saqonfnf/1/ I checked with chrome, ff and ie. The first link has both libraries as external resources. This is not correct added, so this one you must believe that is without libraries added.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found the solution.
It's necessary to define this script between JQuery and JQuery.mobile declarations:

```
<script>
    // Preload configuration
    $( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
        $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
    });
</script>
```

This prevents that JQuery.mobile initializes anything automatically.

Also note that by default, jQuery Mobile sets visibility : hidden on the  element, so you'll need a CSS rule to overwrite that:

```
body {
    visibility : visible !important;
}
```

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319111/how-to-ignore-all-css-elements-in-jquery-mobile) . Thanks to Jasper who provided the solution in this other thread.